# Scheduled BigQuery Not Processing any Data

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm scheduling a query to feed a table everyday with the data from the previous day. When I run the query manually it works without a problem, but when the scheduled query runs it says it doesn't process any data.

```
    SELECT
  event_date,
  event_name,
  event_param.key AS Property,
  event_param.value.double_value,
  event_param.value.string_value,
  event_param.value.int_value,
  user_pseudo_id AS Install_ID,
  COUNT(event_name) AS Event_Count
FROM `XXXX.events_*`
JOIN
  UNNEST (event_params) AS event_param
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX = FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d', DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6,
  7
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong in this case?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVzrZ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcPkY.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the exact same query as a scheduled query, and I saw no problem:

[image]

As this is a scheduled query, is it possible that at the time it ran the previous day table has not been created yet?

Try scheduling the same query, but 2 days off instead:

```
DATE_SUB(current_date(), INTERVAL 2 DAY)
```

Comment: Felipe, I believe the issue is that the scheduled queries were scheduled for times when I was not on my computer (not sure if they would work if I have BigQuery, Firebase, etc closed). I scheduled two queries, one at 4 am and the other at 10 am and 3pm. The one at 4am presented the same issue while the one at 10am or 3pm (when I'm working) worked without a problem. 

I'm hoping this is a bug and will be corrected b/c I don't wanna be worrying about being on my computer at the time the query is supposed to run lol. Also, please let me know if you might have a workaround for this in mind!

Comment: I think the problem is not that you are at a computer or not, but if the table from the previous day exists or not... can you paste the table creation time?

Comment: You're definitely right Felipe, I just checked and the one at 10 am did work even though I wasn't working hehe Thank you for responding!!